# 64-bit SQLGetStmtAttr writes 8 bytes to value buffer when returning SQLUINTEGER

Tags: c++, sql-server, odbc, 32bit-64bit

I'm surprised by what I'm seeing in this block of code:

```
SQLUINTEGER uiCursorType;
SQLINTEGER  iLength;
SQLRETURN sSQLReturn;
sSQLReturn = SQLGetStmtAttr( shStmtHandle, SQL_ATTR_CURSOR_TYPE, &uiCursorType, SQL_IS_UINTEGER, &iLength);
```

I was initially tipped off that a problem may exist here because when the containing function returns, the Visual Studio (remote) debugger tells me that there is stack corruption near the variable `uiCursorType`. Investigating further I find that it's likely correct about that. After the `SQLGetStmtAttr` function executes, the value in `uiCursorType` is `2` and the value in `iLength` is `8`. Checking the values of `sizeof(uiCursorType)` and `sizeof(SQLUINTEGER)` in the debugger, it reports `4` for both. But I'm led to believe from the value put into `iLength` that the function actually wrote 8 bytes. I don't see how the code could be any more clear about the value it's expecting back matching the variable buffer it has provided: `SQLUINTEGER` and `SQL_IS_UINTEGER` seem pretty well-matched. Is this function buggy on 64-bit platforms?

Doing a Google search, I found some sort of patch at http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/libreoffice/2012-January/024859.html that appears to be related, but I don't know how to find more information about it. Is there more information about this problem and how to fix it available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you use a `SQLULEN` as Buffer (your `uiCursorType`)? In 64bit `SQLULEN`is defined to `INT64`, which would be the 8 byte you are observing.

The Doc at Microsoft about `SQL_ATTR_CURSOR_TYPE` ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712631%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ) says that the value is `SQLULEN`.

> SQL_ATTR_CURSOR_TYPE (ODBC 2.0)
>   An SQLULEN value that specifies the cursor type:

Also **note that the driver will most probably ignore the value of `BufferLength`,** if the attribute is not a string or binary attribute ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms715438%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ):

> If Attribute is an ODBC-defined attribute and *ValuePtr is an integer, BufferLength is ignored.

Comment: Why does SQL_IS_UINTEGER exist... for use in other contexts?

Comment: No idea, I havent been using SQL_IS_UINTEGER.